# Drive suddenly out of RAID 0 group

Tags: boot, raid

I have 3 disks grouped in a RAID  0 array.

For a reasons unknown, the RAID configurator sees 2 disks in the group. The 3rd is listed as a normal drive.
Windows will not boot since

it detects an error.

If I put the 3rd disk back into the group, will I restore the raid or will I lose all the data ? I hope you have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

RAID configuration information is stored on the drives. Assuming that the original RAID 0 configuration of three drives was functioning properly before, the drive that was kicked out should still have the RAID 0 configuration information.

If you try to add the drive back in, there should be an alert that pops up saying 'Foreign configuration detected' or something to that effect. You'll want to import the foreign configuration as this is what will allow your drive to become part of the RAID array again.

I'm not sure what RAID controller/software you are using and the previous steps can be implementation dependent and easy to mess up, sometimes wiping the drive in the process. So be careful and always keep backups ( hopefully it isn't too late on this last ).